# Triggered send Emails exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I am completely struggling with exacttarget's triggered sends. I want to set up a trigger send which will send an email as soon as a subscribers comes in to a DE.

So far I have created a triggered send data extension, a triggered send definition. which is activated and when I import any subscriber to this DE nothing happens.

what I need is to send email to any subscriber who comes in to this DE no matter if its a manual import or a file transfer activity or if data is being pushed via JSON Payload.

Can somebody guide me how to do if I do not know how to code. is it possible without knowledge of code?

Comment: Hi Pragyanshu, Triggered Sends are only for use with API (REST/SOAP) usage. Importing (File Import or Query) will not trigger this email type to send. Can you provide more detail about your problem? You may need multiple email send types to solve this problem.

Comment: @cameron I will be glad if you can share an example or a step to step guide how to set up triggered send via API with dummy code. :) JAVA is something I can understand a bit.

Comment: @pragyanshukukreti you would need to pass a SOAP envelope to be consumed by SFMC.  You can find documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send_triggeredsend_email.htm. Stack overflow operates a "show us what you tried" policy and asking for code to be written for you is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to avoid "coding", I can't think of a method that will achieve this.  What I can suggest is this "hack".

1. Create an extra column that will serve as a flag for your exclusion criteria. This will prevent you from sending the message to people that have already received them.
2. In the body of your email, Use the [Update Data Extension Function](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/updatede/) to update the flag in the data extension (e.g you can use a friendly word like "sent").
3. Go to Automation Studio and configure an email to be sent to that data extension. This will not be real time, it would have to be an hourly job.
4. Enter the exlusion script (e.g DE_Column = "sent") in the email set up.

Not perfect but hope it brings you closer to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Data_Kid for this useful information. This surely is going to help me in some other ways but at present this is not what I was looking for as it will take one hour to filter and sent out emails. What I think of was to create an automation with file drop event and send emails via automation to a particular DE which is set to overwrite but for this again CODING is needed to transfer those files to FTP server our developer tried but he was not successful connecting to FTP sever. It is working fine on filezilla but not getting connected through code.

Comment: You are almost there then. I would suggest opening another question and posting the code that the developer is currently using to pass information to the SFTP.