# UpdateDE, Data Extension function help

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dataextensions

I read the following thread and I am trying to implement the idea that involves updating the data extension with the UpdateDE function and hourly emails.

[Triggered send Emails exacttarget](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164608/triggered-send-emails-exacttarget)

I am not able to get my email to recocgnize the UpdateDE function though. Here is my code:

```
%%[

UpdateDE("PosterGuard Large Accounts 
Leads",1,"Phone",%%Phone%%,"EmailName","Sent")

]%%

<pre>New Lead Info:

First Name: %%FirstName%%
Last Name: %%LastName%%
Email Address: %%Email%%
Phone Number: %%Phone%%
Lead Captured At: %%Date%%

</pre>

</html>
```

When i preview the email i see this in the email:

```
%%[ UpdateDE("PosterGuard Large Accounts Leads",1,"Phone",%%Phone%%,"EmailName","Sent") ]%%
```

And when I use the send preview functionality i get this error:

Unable to generate preview
There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.

Error 1: Invalid Function Call
The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.
Function Call: `UpdateDE("PosterGuard Large Accounts Leads",1,"Phone",%%Phone%%,"EmailName","Sent")`

Attribute or Field Name: `%%Phone%%`

Invalid Content: `<br>UpdateDE("PosterGuard Large Accounts Leads",1,"Phone",%%Phone%%,"EmailName","Sent")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `updateDE` function change the `%%Phone%%` to `[Phone]`

```
%%=UpdateDE("PosterGuard Large Accounts Leads",1,"Phone",[Phone],"EmailName","Sent")=%%
```